# why is this variable out of scope? javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

The code below does not run, and I think this is due to the line:

```
alert(nodes[i].getX());
```

I think nodes[i] is out of scope? If so, why?

(I have commented out much of the code to isolate the problem. Basically, the code creates 10 circles, then 10 curves, and then animates them in a canvas with kineticjs).

Thx!

The code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }
            canvas {
                border: 1px solid #9C9898;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v3.9.7.js"></script>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {

                // global parameters
                var curvatureX = 10;
                var curvatureY = 10;
                var nodeRadius = 10;

                var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
                    container: "container",
                    width: 578,
                    height: 300
                });
                var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();


                var nodes = [];

                for (i = 0;i<10;i++){
                    nodes[i] = new Kinetic.Circle({
                        x: i*20,
                        y: i*5,
                        z:1,
                        radius: nodeRadius,
                        fill: "blue",
                        stroke: "black",
                        strokeWidth: 4
                    });
                    layer.add(nodes[i]);
                    alert(nodes[i].getX()); // *** THIS ALERT DOES SHOW UP***

                }


                var edges = [];
                for (i = 0;i<10;i++){

                    edges[i]= new Kinetic.Shape({
                        drawFunc: function() {
                            var context = this.getContext();
                            context.beginPath();

                            // ***WHERE THE PROBLEM IS ***     
                            alert(nodes[i].getX()); 
                            //ALERT DOES NOT SHOW UP + BLANK SCREEN

//                            context.moveTo(nodes[i].getX(), nodes[i].getY());
//                            if (nodes[i].getY()-nodes[i+1].getY()<0){
//                                context.quadraticCurveTo((nodes[i].getX()+nodes[i+1].getX()+curvatureX)/2, (nodes[i].getY()+nodes[i+1].getY()-curvatureY)/2, nodes[i+1].getX(), nodes[i+1].getY());
//                            }
//                            else{
//                                context.quadraticCurveTo((nodes[i].getX()+nodes[i+1].getX()+curvatureX)/2, (nodes[i].getY()+nodes[i+1].getY()+curvatureY)/2, nodes[i+1].getX(), nodes[i+1].getY());
//                            
//                            }
                            context.lineWidth = 10;
                            // line color
                            context.strokeStyle = "black";
                            context.stroke();
                        },
                        fill: "#00D2FF",
                        stroke: "black",
                        strokeWidth: 4
                    });
                    layer.add(edges[i]);
                }



                stage.add(layer);

                var amplitude_1 = 100;
                var amplitude_2 = 30;
                var period = 2000;
                // in ms
                var centerX = stage.getWidth() / 2;
                var centerY = stage.getHeight() / 2;

                stage.onFrame(function(frame) {
                    for (i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){
                        nodes[i].setX(amplitude_1 * i * Math.sin(frame.time * 2 * Math.PI / period) + centerX);
                        nodes[i].setY(amplitude_2 * i+ 20);
                    }
                    layer.draw();

                });

                stage.start();
            };

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does _"does not run"_ mean? he's to old for this shit or what?

Comment: the page remains blank (no circles or curves displayed).

Comment: Did you try debugging the code?

Comment: alert(nodes[i].getX());  is commented out.

Comment: yes but I did not get a clue (I am not an expert with Firebug though)

Comment: `i` will not be what you think it is..

Comment: I see bouncing cicrles with chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/Sf9bL/

Comment: Carl, sorry for the confusion. I deleted the comments on this line, as I wanted to show that these alert on this line was displayed (contrary to the one below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It [displayed](http://jsfiddle.net/uwLyN/). Use the a develop toolbar to do some debug.